# How to change axis titles when using sliders in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm plotting scatter3d projections of the 4d iris data set using plotly. To display all 4 possible projections in the same figure I am using sliders. However when "sliding" from one projection to the next the axis titles do not change. Normally I would use `fig.update_layout()` but that isn't working. How can I get these to change with the slider?

[Projection 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPqil.png)

[Projection 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TbZc.png)

Here's the code for reference:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from matplotlib import cm
from itertools import combinations

def nd2scatter3d(X, labels = None, features = None, plot_axes = None, hovertext = None):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like, shape = (n_samples, n_features).

    labels : 1d int array, shape = (n_samples), optional, default None.
        Target or clustering labels for each sample.
        Defaults to np.ones(n_samples).

    features : list, len = n_features, optional, default None.
        List of feature names.
        Defaults to numeric labeling.

    plot_axes : list of 3-tuples, optional, default None.
        List of axes to include in 3d projections. i.e. [(0,1,2), (0,1,3)] displays
        projections along the 4th axis and 3rd axis in that order.
        Defaults to all possible axes combinations.

    hovertext : list, len = n_samples, optional, default None.
        List of text to display on mouse hover.
        Defaults to no text on hover.
    """
    if labels is None:
        labels = np.ones(X.shape[0]).astype(int)
    if features is None:
        features = np.arange(X.shape[1]).astype(str)
    if plot_axes is None:
        plot_axes = list(combinations(np.arange(X.shape[1]), 3))
    if hovertext is None:
        hoverinfo = 'none'
    else:
        hoverinfo = 'text'

    fig = go.Figure()
    for i in range(len(plot_axes)):
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter3d(
                visible=False,
                x=X[:, plot_axes[i][0]],
                y=X[:, plot_axes[i][1]],
                z=X[:, plot_axes[i][2]],
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(
                    size=3,
                    color = [list(cm.tab10.colors[c]) for c in labels],
                    opacity=1
                ),
                hovertemplate=None,
                hoverinfo= hoverinfo,
                hovertext = hovertext,
              ),)

    fig.data[0].visible = True
    steps = []
    for i in range(len(fig.data)):
        step = dict(
            method="update",
            args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
                  {"title": features[plot_axes[i][0]] + ' vs. ' + features[plot_axes[i][1]] + ' vs. ' + features[plot_axes[i][2]]},  # layout attribute
                 ],
            label = str(plot_axes[i]),
                    )

        step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
        steps.append(step)

    sliders = [dict(
        active=10,
        currentvalue={"prefix": "Projection: "},
        pad={"t": 10},
        steps=steps,
                )]


    fig.update_layout(
        sliders=sliders
    )
    fig.update_layout(width=900, height = 500, margin=dict(r=45, l=45, b=10, t=50),
                     showlegend=False)

    fig.update_layout(scene_aspectmode='cube',
                      scene2_aspectmode='cube',
                      scene3_aspectmode='cube',
                      scene4_aspectmode='cube',
                      scene = dict(
                        xaxis_title = features[plot_axes[0][0]],
                        yaxis_title = features[plot_axes[0][1]],
                        zaxis_title = features[plot_axes[0][2]],),
                      scene2 = dict(
                        xaxis_title = features[plot_axes[1][0]],
                        yaxis_title = features[plot_axes[1][1]],
                        zaxis_title = features[plot_axes[1][2]],),
                      scene3 = dict(
                        xaxis_title = features[plot_axes[2][0]],
                        yaxis_title = features[plot_axes[2][1]],
                        zaxis_title = features[plot_axes[2][2]],),
                      scene4 = dict(
                        xaxis_title = features[plot_axes[3][0]],
                        yaxis_title = features[plot_axes[3][1]],
                        zaxis_title = features[plot_axes[3][2]],)
                     )
    fig.show()
```

**Solution** thanks to jayveesea, as well as some minor changes:

```
def nd2scatter3d(X, labels = None, features = None, plot_axes = None, hovertext = None, size = 3):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like, shape = (n_samples, n_features).

    labels : 1d int array, shape = (n_samples), optional, default None.
        Target or clustering labels for each sample.
        Defaults to np.ones(n_samples).

    features : list, len = n_features, optional, default None.
        List of feature names.
        Defaults to numeric labeling.

    plot_axes : list of 3-tuples, optional, default None.
        List of axes to include in 3d projections. i.e. [(0,1,2), (0,1,3)] displays
        projections along the 4th axis and 3rd axis in that order.
        Defaults to all possible axes combinations.

    hovertext : list, len = n_samples, optional, default None.
        List of text to display on mouse hover.
        Defaults to no text on hover.
    size : int, default 3.
        Sets marker size.
    """

    if labels is None:
        # Label all datapoints zero.
        labels = np.zeros(X.shape[0]).astype(int)
    if features is None:
        # numerical features if no names are passed.
        features = np.arange(X.shape[1]).astype(str)
    if plot_axes is None:
        # plot all possible axes if none are passed.
        plot_axes = list(combinations(np.arange(X.shape[1]), 3))
    if hovertext is None:
        hoverinfo = 'none'
    else:
        hoverinfo = 'text'

    # Determine colormap from number of labels.
    if len(np.unique(labels)) <= 10:
        color = [list(cm.tab10.colors[c]) if c >= 0 else [0,0,0,1] for c in labels]
    elif len(np.unique(labels)) <= 20:
        color = [list(cm.tab20.colors[c]) if c >= 0 else [0,0,0,1] for c in labels]
    else:
        norm_labels = labels/max(labels)
        color = [cm.viridis(c) if c >= 0 else [0,0,0,1] for c in norm_labels]

    # Genterate 3d scatter plot slider.
    fig = go.Figure()
    for i in range(len(plot_axes)):
        fig.add_trace(
            # Scatter plot params.
            go.Scatter3d(
                visible=False,
                x=X[:, plot_axes[i][0]],
                y=X[:, plot_axes[i][1]],
                z=X[:, plot_axes[i][2]],
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(
                    size=size,
                    color = color,
                    opacity=1
                ),
                hovertemplate=None,
                hoverinfo= hoverinfo,
                hovertext = hovertext,
              ),)

    fig.data[0].visible = True
    steps = []

    # Slider update params.
    for i in range(len(fig.data)):
        step = dict(
            method="update",
            args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
                  {"title": features[plot_axes[i][0]] + ' vs. ' 
                       + features[plot_axes[i][1]] + ' vs. ' + features[plot_axes[i][2]],
                   "scene.xaxis.title": features[plot_axes[i][0]],
                   "scene.yaxis.title": features[plot_axes[i][1]],
                   "scene.zaxis.title": features[plot_axes[i][2]],
                  },
                 ],
            label = str(plot_axes[i]),
            )

        step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible".
        steps.append(step)

    sliders = [dict(
        active=10,
        currentvalue={"prefix": "Projection: (x, y, z) = "},
        pad={"t": 10},
        steps=steps,
                )]
    fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders)
    fig.update_layout(width=900, height = 500, margin=dict(r=45, l=45, b=10, t=50))
    fig.update_layout(scene_aspectmode='cube')
    fig.show()
```

Comment: where does `combinations` come from?  I'm getting `name 'combinations' is not defined` from `plot_axes = list(combinations(np.arange(X.shape[1]), 3))`.

Comment: Oh sorry. Lemme edit the post to add all the imports.

Comment: I don't see a link between the slider and the scenes.  as is, it will always use the first scene.  I think the slider needs to update the layout as well.  Have you considered three sliders, one for each axis?

Comment: did the revision to the `update` method work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the axis titles you need to include the axis names with your slider entry.  It may help to reference [plotly's js document on `update`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate).

So instead of this chunk:

```py
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
        step = dict(
            method="update",
            args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
                  {"title": features[plot_axes[i][0]] + ' vs. ' 
                       + features[plot_axes[i][1]] + ' vs. ' + features[plot_axes[i][2]]},
                 ],
            label = str(plot_axes[i]),
                    )
```

Use something like:

```py
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
        step = dict(
            method="update",
            args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
                  {"title": features[plot_axes[i][0]] + ' vs. ' 
                       + features[plot_axes[i][1]] + ' vs. ' + features[plot_axes[i][2]],
                   "scene.xaxis.title": features[plot_axes[i][0]],
                   "scene.yaxis.title": features[plot_axes[i][1]],
                   "scene.zaxis.title": features[plot_axes[i][2]],
                  },
                 ],
            label = str(plot_axes[i]),
            )
```

This creates an entry that will update the data and title and the axes titles when the slider changes.

Comment: This works! I am going to add it to the initial question.